# How to get public path of the css bundle in webpack dev server?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using webpack and webpack-dev-server and currently developing a web application using vue.js and express.js

webpack is bundling all js files into a single js file and the script is being used in the index.html.

```
<script src="/public-path/bundle-name.js" />
```

webpack also loads all CSS files using various CSS loaders such as css-loader and sass-loader and the bundle goes into the memory.

I am in need of linking the CSS bundle like the JS bundle but I do not know the public path.
I know I can use "html-webpack-plugin" which can inject the stylesheets into index.html but because the HTML is being sent from the express server, I can't use the plugin

I'd appreciate it if you can help me with this. I've spent a couple of days to figure this out but ended up posting it here.

Best

Comment: are you using [MiniCssExtractPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/)?

Comment: I added a proxy option to the webpack-dev-server and forwarded all requests to the express backend. The express backend then sends an HTML in the response. Because 'publicPath' in the webpack config is '/assets/" and the JS bundle name is "bundle.js" so linking "/assets/bundle.js" in the HTML works. I mean the JS bundle is running on the browser.

Comment: I tried to use MiniCssExtractPlugin but not sure how to use the extract CSS in the HTML

Comment: If you are not using MiniCssExtractPlugin  all the .css are converted to your .js bundles. are you looking for compiles .css files inside your .js bundles? cause thats what you need to be looking for in this case

Comment: Can .css files be embedded in .js bundles?

Comment: sure. `style-loader` is responsible for manipulating the generated .css from `css-loader` so that when the browser executes the compiled .css it will add them as .css rules.

Comment: Just linking the JS bundle in the HTML does not have any stylesheets on the browser. I am using vue-style-loader so if .css files are embedded into the JS bundle, the stylesheet should be there.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand

Comment: @RazRonen I just figured out this issue. MiniCssExtractPlugin worked. The webpack configuration was correct but the problem was that I did not add rel="stylesheet" to the link tag for importing the css bundle.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you resolved the issue :)